# error when onCreate database is called. Android Studios

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I have looked at several different videos and questions on here about similar issues and my code seems to be fine but just can not figure out why it has an error when compiling **onCreate** in my Database class.

I am only attempting to create and add a row to the database.

This is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText First, Last, Make, Model, Cost;

Button Add;
Context dx = this;
DatabaseOps mydb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DatabaseOps(this);

    First = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.First_Name);
    Last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Last_Name);
    Make = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Car_Make);
    Model = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Car_Model);
    Cost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Car_Cost);
    Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    addData();

}
public void addData()
{
    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean ifInserted = mydb.InsertData(First.getText().toString(),
                    Last.getText().toString(),
                    Make.getText().toString(),
                    Model.getText().toString(),
                    Cost.getText().toString());
            if (ifInserted == true) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successful entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "UnSuccessful entry TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    });
}
```

}

This is the Database class

```
public class DatabaseOps extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

public static final String ID = "ID";
public static final String CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = "Customer First Name";
public static final String CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = "Customer Last Name";
public static final String CAR_MAKE = "Car Make";
public static final String CAR_MODEL = "Car Model";
public static final String COST = "Cost";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CAR_DEALER.db";
public static final String Table_name = "CUSTOMER_TABLE";
public static final String Table_create = "create table"+ Table_name + "(" +
        ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"+
        CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME +"TEXT" +
        CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME +"TEXT" +
        CAR_MAKE +"TEXT" +
        CAR_MODEL +"TEXT" +
        COST +"Integer"
        +")";



public DatabaseOps(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    Log.d("DatabaseOps", "Success Database created!" );
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{

    db.execSQL(Table_create);
    Log.d("DatabaseOps", "Success Table created!" );


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
{
    db.execSQL("Drop Table IF Exists" +Table_name);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean InsertData (String First, String Last, String Make, String Model, String Cost)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, First);
    cv.put(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, Last);
    cv.put(CAR_MAKE, Make);
    cv.put(CAR_MODEL, Model);
    cv.put(COST, Cost);
    Long result = db.insert(Table_name, null, cv);
    if( result == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}


}
```

I was thinking it could be an issue with the manifest file not initializing the database class, however the manifest says there was no default constructor in the class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is completely with the contents of `Table_create` and your column names.

First you need spaces between key words and values. `"create table" + Table_name` resolves to `"create tableCUSTOMER_TABLE"`.

Second you should not put spaces in your column names. So instead of `"Car Model"` use `"Car_Model"` for example.

It helps, just to print the string. See [create-table-stmt](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/create-table-stmt.html) for more information.

Comment: You also need commas after each type.